# Unable to mount root fs

Tags: mount, linux-kernel, live-usb, kernel-panic

I get kernel panic from my freshly compiled linux kernel
booting from USB key (like here [Unable to mount root fs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Knowledge_Base:Unable_to_mount_root_fs))

```
 1. error      : unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
 2. kernel version : 5.5-rc5
 3. bootloader : none (EFI stub)
 4. built-in kernel command line : root=PARTUUID=xx1-xx1-xx1-1xx
 5. root file system : f2fs
 6. kernel is moduleless
```

Solutions tried/tested

```
 1. kernel supports the filesystem on root
 2. checked PARTUUID of the root device 3 times
 3. no modules 
 4. kernel do load my sata ssd with proper PARTUUID
 5. kernel doesn't mount other USB drive
 6. BLK_DEV=y, BLK_DEV_SD=y, USB_STORAGE=y, ...
 7. tried with UUID and /dev/sda2 same result
```

It seems to be a USB problem something wrong in kernel configuration ?

some links already checked
[Unable to mount root fs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Knowledge_Base:Unable_to_mount_root_fs), 
[not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0 0)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414655/not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)

Comment: Check [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67477/issues-with-root-partuuid-in-cmdline-txt-at-boot) out ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ok it turns to be a slow USB subsystem.
- rootwait added to the kernel command line fixed that

all the credit goes to NeddySeagoon from [Gentoo Forum](https://forums.gentoo.org/) 
link to the post [Unable to mount root fs](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8407080.html#8407080)